# Is there an editor for pig code and will it help to debug the pig code

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to hadoop and pig so would want to know is there any pig editor or any plugin available for pig editor. is there a way to debug pig code? and also how often we debug and unit test the code in real time environment.

Comment: You can run each command in the grunt shell individually and see the `DUMP`. Is that considered debugging?

Comment: i think there is no such editor..